# Benders subproblem feasible region dependent upon solution master problem

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, nonlinear-programming, benders-decomposition

Suppose I want to solve a naturally MINLP problem of the following form:
$$
\min_{x,y} \{c'x + y \mid Ax \leq b, Dx + Ey \leq f, G(x)y\leq g, x \in \mathbb{Z}, y \in \mathbb{R}^+\}
$$
Here $G(x)$ indicates that the matrix $G$ is dependent upon $x$. Thinking of Benders Decomposition, I would end up with a dual subproblem of the form (for a given $\bar{x}$)
$$
\max_{y\mid \bar{x}} \{(f - D\bar{x})'u + g'v \mid E'u + G(\bar{x})'v \geq 1, \ u,v\in\mathbb{R}^+\}
$$

However, now the feasible region of the subproblem depends upon $x$. Does this automatically implies that this approach does not make sense? I have only a basic understanding of Benders Decomposition, but I assume that there are bright minds that already have studied a setting like this in very much detail. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is $y$ a scalar or a vector? It seems to be scalar in the objective and the variable definition, but $G(x)y \le g$ seems to imply a vector.

Comment: Whether Benders (or something Benders-like) is workable may depend on the nature of $G()$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I always find it helpful to look at Benders decomposition from a primal view, as detailed in [this presentation](http://www.dei.unipd.it/~fisch/papers/slides/2017%20Lunteren%20%5BFischetti%20on%20Benders%5D.pdf) by Matteo Fischetti.

You can write
$$
\min_{x,y} \{c'x + y \mid Ax \leq b, Dx + Ey \leq f, G(x)y\leq g, x \in \mathbb{Z}^n, y \in \mathbb{R}^+\}
$$
as
$$
\min_{x,y} \{c'x + \Phi(x) \mid Ax \leq b, x \in \mathbb{Z}^n\}
$$
with
$$
\Phi(x) = \min_{y} \{y \mid Ey \leq f - Dx, G(x)y\leq g, y \in \mathbb{R}^+\}.
$$

In classical Benders decomposition (i.e., without the non-linear constraint $G(x)y \le g$), the function $\Phi(x)$ is the value function of a linear program when the right-hand side changes. From duality theory, it follows that this function is convex. Benders cuts can then be seen as supporting hyperplanes of the epigraph of $\Phi(x)$.

If the function $\Phi(x)$ is not convex, classical Benders cuts cannot be used. However, because $x \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, you could still use combinatorial Benders cuts, which only support the epigraph at the integer values of $x$ (which is the only thing you are interested in). See [Laporte et al. (2002)](https://doi.org/10.1287/opre.50.3.415.7751) and [Codato & Fischetti (2006)](https://doi.org/10.1287/opre.1060.0286).

Comment: If $G(x)$ is sufficiently annoying (for instance, you get it by looking up one of a rather arbitrary set of matrices based on the values of $x$), and if the subproblem is infeasible at $x=\bar{x}$, will you be able to do any better than a "no-good" cut to remove $\bar{x}$?

Comment: I agree, only using combinatorial Benders cuts is basically adding no-good cuts in this case. This may still be a good strategy. In addition, I would try to find a convex lowerbounding function for $\Phi(x)$ (some sort of relaxation), and add cuts for this.